# Convergence of Newton's Method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, convergence-divergence

Suppose $m \geq 2$ be an integer such that $m \geq 2$, let $a, x_0 >0$. The sequence is then

$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{m}\left( (m-1)x_n + \frac{a}{x^2 _{m+1}} \right )$

Show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a unique positive solution of $x^m = a$

**Attempt**

Honestly, I thought I would just go and prove this without the whole m getting in my way first. So I would try to prove by m = 2 first and then use the fact that $m \geq 2$ to cheat my way through it.

But when I got to the limit part to converging to $x^m = a$, I couldn't get it. I got nothing like it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, it should have been

$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{m}\left( (m-1)x_n + \frac{a}{x^{m-1}_n} \right )$

@ Gerry

When $m = 2$

$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left( (2-1)x_n + \frac{a}{x^{2-1}_n} \right ) = \frac{1}{2}\left( (x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}) \right )$

EDIT2: yes it worked for $m = 2$

Comment: Your idea of proving for $m=2$ first is a good one, but I didn't follow your subsequent remarks: did you succeed for $m=2$ or not?

Comment: What is the point of using this algorithm? If this is a fixed point method (Newton's method is), then you should have that if x_{n+1} = x_n  then x_n^m = a, which is obviously *not* the case here.  Is this homework? Where did this come from? I can't find the mistake by myself in this question, but I don't feel like it'll converge towards a root of $x^m$ because the sequence is not related in anyway to $x^m$. 

Welcome to MSE by the way! =D

Comment: I think the last bit of your formula is wrong. For $m=2$, Newton says $x_{n+1}=x_n-((x_n^2-a)/(2x_n))$, which rewrites as $x_{n+1}=(1/2)(x_n+(a/x_n))$, which isn't what you have.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{m}\left( (m-1)x_n + \frac{a}{x^{m-1}_n} \right )$$

Supposing that the sequence does in fact converge. Then, we can set $x_{n+1}=x_n = x$ in the above equation. If you simplify the resulting expression you should get the desired result.

If, in addition to the above, you have to actually check if the sequence converges then you need additional machinery. See the wiki for a description of the [proof of convergence of Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method) which you may be able to adapt to your setting.